# WPF Data Template Selector

Tags: wpf, templates, contentcontrol

I have a data template selector, which I am using to pick between two different templates. Problem is, these templates include a grid as the outer element etc. What I have done is I have my template selector in my resource control in my UserControl.Resources:

```
<l:UIDataTemplateSelector x:Key="UISelector"
          ClassicDataTemplate="{StaticResource ClassicDataTemplate}"
          ModernDataTemplate="{StaticResource ModernDataTemplate}" />
```

Then outside of this, I have my Content Control, where my templates are in Control Templates:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource UISelector}"></ContentControl>
```

When I run my code, this causes it to crash, but if I use:

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource ClassicDataTemplate}"></ContentControl>
```

To use one template or the other, it works perfectly fine. Is there a simple way to get it to use the template selector to display it?

Answer (score 0):

A `ContentControl` has a `Template` of type `ControlTemplate`. It also accepts a `ContentTemplate` of type `DataTemplate` and a `ContentTemplateSelector` which is expected to select a `DataTemplate`. In your case, since `Template="{StaticResource ClassicDataTemplate}"` is working, I suspect you created `ControlTemplate` instead of `DataTemplate`. You need a working `ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ClassicDataTemplate}"` in order to transfer to the selector.